# How to add vault secrets to kubernetes env vars?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I am using the `OAuth2-Proxy` helm chart which is authenticating using an external oidc provider, along with Vault to store the secrets. Now, in order to pass it the `client-id` & `client-secret` secrets stored in Vault, I followed this link - https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector/examples#environment-variable-example

This shows how to add these secrets as env vars in a container, but `OAuth2-Proxy` needs these variables to start in the first place (They are passed as args to the docker image's entrypoint). I also tried adding the source command to the `postStart` lifecycle method but that also gives the following error -

```
Exec lifecycle hook ([sh -c source /vault/secrets/oidc.sh]) for Container "oauth2-proxy" in Pod "oauth2-proxy-f6c8f7b69-kgjws_istio-system(7e488c12-2964-496f-a658-47739fcf3695)" failed - error: command 'sh -c source /vault/secrets/oidc.sh' exited with 126: , message: "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: cannot exec a container that has stopped: unknown\r\n"
```

I think this is because the docker image's entry-point requires those env vars and the container dies off as soon as that command fails. Is there any other approach for doing this?

Comment: You probably should have a look at external-secrets: https://external-secrets.io/v0.5.6/provider-hashicorp-vault/

Comment: If you are deploying using something like Jenkins or Octopus, then you could simply deploy env variables with the deployment and mask them in the CD tool. This will depend on who has access to what since secrets are only secure if rbac is setup. If someone has access to the container, they will be able to see the secrets where they get mounted.

Comment: feel free to checkout the : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73046067/5525824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to inject vault secrets into the k8s pod as ENV vars using **vault Agent Injector** method

First A template should be created that exports a Vault secret as an environment variable.

```
spec:   template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        # Environment variable export template
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-config: |
          {{ with secret "secret/data/web" -}}
            export api_key="{{ .Data.data.payments_api_key }}"
          {{- end }}
```

And the application container should source those files during startup.

```
args:
  ['sh', '-c', 'source /vault/secrets/config && <entrypoint script>']
```