# sourcing vault secrets file with lifecycle.postStart and readinessProbe

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to `source` a file from `/vault/secrets/cloudquery` which contains data that looks like this:

```
export MYSECRET="REDACTED"
```

I have tried a ton of different things to source the vault secrets file when my pod starts up, but when I shell into the pod, I don't see the env variables set. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!!

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    metadata:
    ...
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: default
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-cloudquery: "path/to/mysecret"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-cloudquery: |
          {{ with secret "path/to/mysecret" -}}
            export MYSECRET="{{ .Data.MYSECRET }}"
          {{- end }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cloudquery
          ...
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "test -e /vault/secrets/cloudquery" ]
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 5
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - "/bin/sh"
                  - "-c"
                  - "source /vault/secrets/cloudquery"
...
```

Comment: This is not really how you would do this in Kubernetes, but also the Vault agent injector does not cleanly support mapping secrets to container environment variables either. You have streamlined options for k8s secret, or container volume mount (but not from a ConfigMap).

Comment: i understand how k8 secrets work, but they encode in base64, which makes those secret.yaml files no good to commit to source control. sourcing a file after a pod comes up should be trivial though in kubernetes right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this if looking forward to inject the environment with POD startup

```
annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-image: <Agent image>
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-secrets: kv/<Path-of-secret>
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-secrets: |2

          {{- with secret "kv/<Path-of-secret>" -}}

          #!/bin/sh
          set -e

          {{- range $key, $value := .Data.data }}
          export {{ $key }}={{ $value }}
          {{- end }}

          exec "$@"
          {{- end }}
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: auth/<K8s cluster for auth>
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: app
```

This will create the file inside your POD.

Inside your Docker file if you are simply running an application `CMD ["node", "index.js"]` instead change **CMD** to running the `CMD ["npm", "start"]`.

Docker/Container will get start the main shell script and it will set all env into OS first. Once all Env is set to shell script will start the application.

**package.json**

```
"start": "./path-to-shscript-in-docker/runapp",
```

**runapp**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f '/vault/secrets/secrets' ]; then
  source '/vault/secrets/secrets'
fi
node <path-insnide-docker>/index.js
```

The issue with the lifecycle hook is that there is no guarantee, so it would be better to call the **source** before the app start.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert data inside your vault to json and use like below:

```
  annotations:
    ...
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-cloudquery: "path/to/mysecret"
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-cloudquery-config: |
      {{ with secret "path/to/mysecret" }}{{ range $k, $v := .Data.data }}
         export {{ $k }}='{{ $v }}'{{ end }}
      {{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I am braindead today and that env vars that get `export` ran on them only exist within the shell they are run in, so when I shell into the pod, I'm not seeing the vars because I'm in a new shell. Going to approach this a different way. Thanks!

Comment: but i think if you will inject it as env it will work with any shell.