# ClientID and ClientCredential management for a multi instance deployment

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

How do you manage clientId and clientCredentials of an OIDC(or OAuth2) application's deployment consisting of multiple instances fronted by let's say an L7 load balancer ?

Do you maintain separate clientId/clientCredential for each application instance ?
If yes, how do you manage clientId/clientCredentials for dynamically provisioned instance (E.g. Kubernetes/AWS adding a new application instance in response to a health check failure or a scale-out event)

If you share clientId/clientCredentials across multiple application instances,Isn't that violating the basic rule (i.e. 'secret' is no longer a secret anymore) ?
Also, Compromise of any individual instance by potential attackers, kind of impacts the entire deployment.

Answer (score 0):

> If you share clientId/clientCredentials across multiple application
> instances,Isn't that violating the basic rule (i.e. 'secret' is no
> longer a secret anymore)

Instead of using the secret, you can leverage the **Hashicorp Vault** which will store and inject the environment variable to the **deployment**. You can implement encryption at rest and other security options like RBAC on vault UI access.

Yes, secret is base64 encoded not encrypted if you have a large team managing a cluster and **RBAC** is not set everyone having access to the cluster will be able to decode the secret.

Read more about the has corp vault : https://www.vaultproject.io/

With Kubernetes : https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-raft-deployment-guide?in=vault%2Fkubernetes

Once the vault is set and you have created the secret into it with values you can refer my answer for more details injecting the secret to deployment : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73046067/5525824

Comment: Hi Harsh,

 Thanks for your reply.But the real issue here is not about ensuring security of clientCredentials. (Although, it's an important security concern to address)
 
 This question is more of a design choice, and understanding implications of each one of them; 
 Using a shared clientId/clientCreds across multiple instances or use a dedicated clientId/clientCreds for each app instance.

Comment: If you have a single deployment with multiple replicas we use the same across multiple instances, however for each defined app in oauth setup it will be different client/creds.

Comment: If you share the clientId/clientCreds across multiple instances of the application, how do you then differentiate the API calls (in logs) made by each individual instance while scanning through the Authorization Server logs ?

Comment: normally we keep the corelation id along with instance id also multiple fields to filter out the logs and calls sequence.