# How to get secrets from external vault with aws eks

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, hashicorp-vault, external-secrets

I am facing minor issue with getting secrets from external vaults to aws eks container.

I am using sidecar container for inject secrets in to pods.

I have created secrets at below path ,

```
vault kv put secrets/mydemo-eks/config username='admin' password='secret'
```

my pod yaml is as below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mydemo
  labels:
    app: mydemo
  annotations:
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status: 'update'
    vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: 'auth/mydemo-eks'
    vault.hashicorp.com/namespace: 'default'
    vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'mydemo-eks-role'
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-credentials.txt: 'secrets/data/mydemo-eks/config' 
spec:
  serviceAccountName: mydemo-sa
  containers:
    - name: myapp
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:       
      - containerPort: 80
```

when i m checking real time logs,

getting as below,

[image]

My Hashicorp Vault policy is as below,

```
vault policy write mydemo-eks-policy - <<EOF
path "secrets/data/mydemo-eks/config" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
EOF
```

actually secrets already there on mentioned path,

[image]

Any idea....

Is there any wrong i have done.

any one have worked on this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: can you check the vault ui and share SS if the secret is exist at that path?

Comment: yes it is there.. have verified all.

Comment: this is what i use mostly, `kv` and path of the secret : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73046067/5525824

Comment: An external Vault server paired with the Agent injector init-container to an EKS workload can fail in a seemingly random manner. Your configuration does appear correct. Have you also checked the Vault server logs?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the policy as below,

```
vault policy write mydemo-eks-policy - <<EOF
path "secrets/mydemo-eks/config" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
EOF
```

Earlier i used like ,

```
vault policy write mydemo-eks-policy - <<EOF
path "secrets/data/mydemo-eks/config" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
EOF
```